# Generating an HTML File [PHP]

Tags: php

So basically I have this "gallery" page of mine which works by having a mysql database that stores the references and file names of the images i'm uploading. I also have "albums" where similarly categorized pictures are in there. My question is, I would like php to generate me an html file whenever I would like to have a new album (since this albums are just href's to another html page that contains the images). I know how to use fopen() and fwrite() but my problem is, how can I create a string that would be able to hold a WHOLE HTML DOCUMENT formatting? That doesn't require me to escape double quotes and such anymore?

Comment: just like this `$your_data = fetch_from_mysql();` and `$html = '<html><body><div>'.$your_data.'</div></body></html>';` now create that function and return the data as you want to show/store.

Comment: But my problem is, I do have lots of double quotations in my HTML General Format, I'm asking if there's anyway that I can do so that I wouldn't have the need to escape such double quotes anymore? Anw, thanks for that! ;D

Comment: Your data may have double quotation, it does not matter. Just use them inside the single quota.

Comment: @FrayneKonok No, that's not appropriate.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.

Comment: @Brad, Thanks for the message..

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is a templating engine, such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Next, you can write static HTML files to disk if you want... but consider outputting them dynamically.  Use rewrite rules to point your galleries at a single PHP scripts that generates these.  It tends to be more manageable.

(There are situations where static files can be useful... such as distributing to CDNs and what not.  But I'm guessing that for your case, a dynamic page is sufficient.)